# 2 circle questions

Tags: geometry

1) I need a hint on this one that I know how to solve using trigonometry but not geometry:

> Find the equation of a circle that touches $x$-axis in the $(0, 0)$, and touches the circle of a known equation $(x-6)^2 + (y-13)^2=25$.

I tried everything but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

2)

> There are 2 points that the circle touches A(-3, 2) and B(1, 0), and a line of an equation: $y=x+4$ on which is the center of the circle. Find the equation of the circle.

My way: get 2 equations:

$(-3-p)^2+(2-q)^2=r^2$

$(1-p)^2+q^2=r^2$

Now I supstituate $r^2$ and find

$3+2p-q=0$

Now I change $y=x+4$ into $q=p+4$ and get the correct result, is this a good way, or is there an easier way of solving this problem?

Comment: By middle of circle, you mean centre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1:** The centre is on $(0,a)$. What is its distance from the centre of other circle?

**2:** The centre of circle must lie on perpendicular bisector of $AB$. Can you now find the centre? Its radius is distance of centre from...

Comment: 1-Damn, I did that already, I've compared the distances, I have mistaken in the calculation so I thought I didn't know how to solve this. Thank you anyways.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @fff Welcome to Math SE. You can accept an answer by ticking on the tick button below arrows near an answer.

Comment: 2-English is not my main language, I assume You said that the center must be on a line that lies in the middle of the line that connects these 2 points and is 90 degree to it, a so called "normal"? So then I can find where the 2 lines cross and there's the center. Nice, thanks.

Comment: @Jacob Yes. Well done.